Телеграм бот не реагирует на сообщение в группе. python aiogram
Бот отправляет сообщение в группу с кнопкой. После нажатия этой кнопки он просит ввести полную цену заказа. Но почему-то не реагирует. Состояние объявил и бот переходит на него, но функция обработки не срабатывает.
Код:
async def handle_enter_price(self, callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    order_id = callback_query.data.split('_')[2]
    await state.update_data(order_id=order_id)

    await callback_query.message.answer("Введіть загальну ціну збірки для всіх товарів:")
    await state.set_state(Form.waiting_for_total_price_input)

    current_state = await state.get_state()
    print(f"Поточний стан: {current_state}")

async def process_total_price_input(self, message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        total_assembly_price = float(message.text.strip())
    except ValueError:
        await message.answer("Некоректне значення ціни. Введіть число.")
        return

    data = await state.get_data()
    order_id = data['order_id']
    print(order_id)

    # Оновлення загальної ціни в базі даних
    sql_requests.update_total_order_price(order_id, total_assembly_price)

    # Надсилання підсумкового повідомлення замовнику
    contractor_chat_id = sql_requests.get_contractor_chat_id(order_id)
    products_info = "\n".join(
        [f"Товар: {p['product']}, Артикул: {p['article']}, Вартість збірки: {total_assembly_price} грн" for p in
         data['products']]
    )

    await self.bot.send_message(contractor_chat_id,
                                f"Ціна на збірку оновлена:\n"
                                f"{products_info}\n"
                                f"Загальна вартість збірки: {total_assembly_price} грн"
                                )

    # Надсилання повідомлення в канал
    await self.send_to_channel(data, order_id)
    await state.clear()

Регистрация состояния:
self.dp.message.register(self.process_total_price_input, Form.waiting_for_total_price_input)


У бота есть права на чтение сообщений в группе? Без них он конечно реагировать не будет

Что-то я про это не подумал даже, странно. Сейчас узнаю и отпишусь, так как я не могу сам посмотреть. Если так, то напишете ответ и я отмечу как решение

Да, оно)) Пишите ответ. Спасибо

Боты не имеют права читать обычные сообщения в группах в целях безопасности. Если нужно реализовать какой-либо функционал с чтением сообщений то не забудьте выдать ему нужные права
